# Map to a Trans capacity request from transit(Nodal) points using pandas dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, mapping, operations-research

## Input Dataframe With TerminalID,TName,XY cordinate, PeopleID

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'TerminalID': ['5','21','21','2','21','2','5','22','22','22','2','32','41','41','42','50','50'],
        'TName': ['AD','AMBO','AMBO','PS','AMBO','PS','AD','AM','AM','AM','PS','BO','BA','BA','BB','AZ','AZ'],
        'xy': ['1.12731,1.153756','0.12731,0.153757','0.12731,0.153757','1.989385,1.201941','0.12731,0.153757','1.989385,1.201941','1.12731,1.153756','2.12731,1.153756','2.12731,1.153756','2.12731,1.153756','1.989385,1.201941','1.989385,1.201941','2.989385,1.201941','2.989385,1.201941','2.989385,3.201941','3.989385,3.201941','3.989385,3.201941'],
        'Pcode': [ 'None','Z014','Z015','Z016','Z017','Z018','None','Z020','Z021','Z022','Z023','Z024','Z025','Z026','Z027','Z028','Z029']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

## Out[55]:

## output of DF1

```
   TerminalID TName                 xy Pcode
0           5    AD   1.12731,1.153756  None
1          21  AMBO   0.12731,0.153757  Z014
2          21  AMBO   0.12731,0.153757  Z015
3           2    PS  1.989385,1.201941  Z016
4          21  AMBO   0.12731,0.153757  Z017
5           2    PS  1.989385,1.201941  Z018
6           5    AD   1.12731,1.153756  None
7          22    AM   2.12731,1.153756  Z020
8          22    AM   2.12731,1.153756  Z021
9          22    AM   2.12731,1.153756  Z022
10          2    PS  1.989385,1.201941  Z023
11         32    BO  1.989385,1.201941  Z024
12         41    BA  2.989385,1.201941  Z025
13         41    BA  2.989385,1.201941  Z026
14         42    BB  2.989385,3.201941  Z027
15         50    AZ  3.989385,3.201941  Z028
16         50    AZ  3.989385,3.201941  Z029
```

## DF2,

T_cap is the capacity requirement at the Terminal ID and the T_load is the Load details, Tcap is the running count increment and T_load is the actual request at the Termainal,
The 0 at the start and the end are padding for the solution

```
data2= {
        'BusID': ['18','18','18','18','18','18','18','18','18'],
        'Tcap': ['0','2','3','6','7','8','10','12','12'],
        'T_Load': ['0','2','1','2','2','1','2','2','0'],
        'TerminalID': [ '5','21','33','2','32','42','41','50','5'],
        
        'TName':['AD','AMBO','AM','PS','BO','BB','BA','AZ','AD']
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
```

## Out[59]:

```
  BusID Tcap T_Load TerminalID TName
0    18    0      0          5    AD
1    18    2      2         21  AMBO
2    18    3      1         33    AM
3    18    6      2          2    PS
4    18    7      2         32    BO
5    18    8      1         42    BB
6    18   10      2         41    BA
7    18   12      2         50    AZ
8    18   12      0          5    AD
```

## Data Frame # the Final output requested

The output is based on the T_Load contstrains.

```
data3 = {
        'BusID': ['18','18','18','18','18','18','18','18','18'],
        'Tcap': ['0','2','3','6','7','8','10','12','12'],
        'T_Load': ['0','2','1','3','1','1','2','2','0'],
        'TerminalID': [ '5','21','33','2','32','42','41','50','5'],
        
        'TName':['AD','AMBO','AM','PS','BO','BB','BA','AZ','AD'],
        'Pcode':['None','Z013,Z019','Z020','Z016,Z018,Z023','Z024','Z027','Z025,Z026','Z028,Z029','None']
    }
    
    df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data3)
```

## Out[61]:

```
  BusID Tcap T_Load TerminalID TName           Pcode
0    18    0      0          5    AD            None
1    18    2      2         21  AMBO       Z013,Z019
2    18    3      1         33    AM            Z020
3    18    6      3          2    PS  Z016,Z018,Z023
4    18    7      1         32    BO            Z024
5    18    8      1         42    BB            Z027
6    18   10      2         41    BA       Z025,Z026
7    18   12      2         50    AZ       Z028,Z029
8    18   12      0          5    AD            None
```

Thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution aggreagte join per `TerminalID` and `TName` and assign to another DataFrame by aggreagte list, last filter values by positions in list comprehension with `join`:

```
s = df.groupby(['TerminalID','TName'])['Pcode'].agg(list).rename('P_list')
df = df2.join(s, on=['TerminalID','TName'])

df['P_list'] = [','.join(x[:int(y)]) if int(y) != 0 else None 
                for x, y in zip(df['P_list'], df['T_Load'])]
print (df)
  BusID Tcap T_Load TerminalID TName          P_list
0    18    0      0          5    AD            None
1    18    2      2         21  AMBO       Z014,Z015
2    18    3      1         22    AM            Z020
3    18    6      3          2    PS  Z016,Z018,Z023
4    18    7      1         32    BO            Z024
5    18    8      1         42    BB            Z027
6    18   10      2         41    BA       Z025,Z026
7    18   12      2         50    AZ       Z028,Z029
8    18   12      0          5    AD            None
```

Comment: Sorry Jezrael, I need only two P_list in the second row since the T_Load is only 2.. and in the 3rd row I need only 3 three, also in 2nd row I need only 2 as T_Load is 2

Comment: @jesrael, why I am getting float object not sub-scriptable. TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable I see the outputs 3
H11153,Z0001,L0001
H,1,1 the first string is getting splitted.. should I change my inputs to a  single string.. example Z014, Z,0,1, the split is happening character level,

Comment: why I am getting the P_list allocated again..!

Comment: I have added one more question, I this approach I getting pcode repeated for some reason in the assignment, in this question I have given variation in the Vehicle or bus ID, please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72481631/nodal-label-assignment-according-to-the-load-at-a-terminal-in-pandas-data-frame

Comment: I have added few comments above

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` the aggregated strings per TName:

```
df2['Plist'] = df2['TName'].map(df.groupby('TName')['Pcode'].agg(','.join))
```

or, if you want to replace multiple string None as single one:

```
df2['Plist'] = df2['TName'].map(df.groupby('TName')['Pcode']
                                  .agg(lambda x: ','.join(e for e in x if e != 'None'))
                                  .replace('', 'None')
                                )
```

output:

```
  BusID Tcap T_Load TerminalID TName           Plist
0    18    0      0          5    AD            None
1    18    2      2         21  AMBO  Z014,Z015,Z017
2    18    3      1         22    AM  Z020,Z021,Z022
3    18    6      3          2    PS  Z016,Z018,Z023
4    18    7      1         32    BO            Z024
5    18    8      1         42    BB            Z027
6    18   10      2         41    BA       Z025,Z026
7    18   12      2         50    AZ       Z028,Z029
8    18   12      0          5    AD            None
```

###### update: limiting the output:

you can then trim the column with a regex, we can use a `groupby` to benefit from vectorized string operations within each group (this is mostly interesting if there are few groups and many rows):

```
df2['P_list'] = (df2.groupby('T_Load')['P_list']
                    .apply(lambda c: c.str.extract(rf'((?:[^,]+,?){{,{str(c.name)}}})',
                                                   expand=False)
                                    .str.strip(',')
                          )
                    .replace('', 'None')
                )
```

output:

```
  BusID Tcap T_Load TerminalID TName          P_list
0    18    0      0          5    AD            None
1    18    2      2         21  AMBO       Z014,Z015
2    18    3      1         22    AM            Z020
3    18    6      3          2    PS  Z016,Z018,Z023
4    18    7      1         32    BO            Z024
5    18    8      1         42    BB            Z027
6    18   10      2         41    BA       Z025,Z026
7    18   12      2         50    AZ       Z028,Z029
8    18   12      0          5    AD            None
```

Comment: Sorry Mozway, I need only two P_list in the second row since the T_Load is only 2.. and in the 3rd row I need only 3 three, also in 2nd row I need only 2 as T_Load is 2

Comment: then your logic and expected output are unclear, can you double check? For instance there is no 2013 in the input, where is it coming from in the output?

Comment: Mozway which line are you refering?  The first dataframe in the total request, from that we need to map the people to the Terminal_Load, The Plist should only contain the no of item specified in T_Load.

Comment: index 1 of output

Comment: 0    18    0      0          5    AD            None ( you mean this one.)

Comment: `1    18    2      2         21  AMBO       Z013,Z019` <- where does the `2013` come from?

Comment: give me some time I am correcting the inputs again..

Comment: raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Also when I try your approach I am getting duplicate mappings the list is used again.

Comment: @vinsent I might be wise to start a new question (you can reference this one), with a clear example of your new case for which you have issues.

Comment: added another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72481631/nodal-label-assignment-according-to-the-load-at-a-terminal-in-pandas-data-frame, with the current question I getting same Pcode assigned to different bus ID which I wanted to avoid.